# Django Database Prefix

Tags: django, postgresql

I need to merge two databases for two different apps. How can add prefix to all Django tables to avoid any conflict?

For example, option should look like:

```
DB_PREFIX = 'my_prefix_'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to prefixing all the names is to put one of the two DBs into a different schema 
 (multiple schemas can coexist in the same database, even if the objects have the same names) This will also take care of objects other than tables, such as indexes, views, functions, ...

So on one of the databases, just do

```
ALTER SCHEMA public RENAME TO myname;
```

After that, you can dump it (`pg_dump -n myname` to dump only one schema), and import it into the other database, without the chance of collisions.

You refer to tables or other objects in the new schema by `myname.tablname` or by setting the search_path (this can be done on a per-user basis eg via `ALTER USER SET search_path = myschema, pg_catalog;`)

---

Note: there may be a problem with frameworks and clients not being *schema-aware*, so you might need some additional tweaking. YMMV.

---

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-alterschema.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use meta options for model,

```
class ModelHere():
      class Meta:
          db_table = "tablenamehere"
```

**Edit**

If you want to add prefix to all of your tables including auth_user, auth_group, etc. Then you are looking for something like [django-table-prefix](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-table-prefix/0.0.5). Just install and add some settings to settings file and you are done.

1. Add `'table_prefix',` to installed apps,
2. Set the table prefix as `DB_PREFIX = 'nifty_prefix'`

Then run syncdb and the output will be,

```
Creating tables ...
Creating table nifty_prefix_auth_permission
Creating table nifty_prefix_auth_group_permissions
Creating table nifty_prefix_auth_group
Creating table nifty_prefix_auth_user_groups
Creating table nifty_prefix_auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table nifty_prefix_auth_user
Creating table nifty_prefix_django_content_type
Creating table nifty_prefix_django_session
Creating table nifty_prefix_django_site
```

Comment: This one is good and i know it. But i need prefix for whole django tables, including auth_user, auth_group, etc.

Comment: i notice table_prefix, but it doesn't work for django 1.8.

Comment: @copycat  You must mention all of your research and requirement  in question itself. You didn't mentioned in question as you are using django 1.8

Comment: i'll remember it, for future